# What is the tree-structure of a heap?

Tags: c++, heap

I'm reading Nicolai M. Josuttis's "The C++ standard library, a tutorial and reference", ed2.

He explains the heap data structure and related STL functions in page 607:

> The program has the following output:

```
on entry: 3 4 5 6 7 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4
after make_heap(): 9 8 6 7 7 5 5 3 6 4 1 2 3 4
after pop_heap(): 8 7 6 7 4 5 5 3 6 4 1 2 3
after push_heap(): 17 7 8 7 4 5 6 3 6 4 1 2 3 5
after sort_heap(): 1 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 17
```

[image]

I'm wondering how could this be figured out? for example, why the leaf "4" under path 9-6-5-4 is the left side child of node "5", not the right side one? And after `pop_heap` what's the tree structure then? In IDE debugging mode I could only see see the content of the vector, is there a way to figure out the tree structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why the leaf "4" under path 9-6-5-4 is the left side child of node "5", not the right side one?

Because if it was on the right side, that would mean there is a gap in the underlying vector. The tree structure is for illustrative purposes only. It is not a representation of how the heap is actually stored. The tree structure is mapped onto the underlying vector via a simple mathematical formula.

The root node of the tree is the first element of the vector (index 0). The index of the left child of a node is obtained from its parent's index by the simple formula: `i * 2 + 1`. And the index of the right child is obtained by `i * 2 + 2`.

> And after pop_heap what's the tree structure then?

<strike>The root node is swapped with the greater of its two children<sup>1</sup>, and this is repeated until it is at the bottom of the tree. Then it is swapped with the last element. This element is then pushed *up* the tree, if necessary, by swapping with its parent if it is greater.</strike>

The root node is swapped with the last element of the heap. Then, this element is pushed down the heap by swapping with the greater of its two children<sup>1</sup>. This is repeated until it is in the correct position (i.e. it is not less than either of its children).

So after pop_heap, your tree looks like this:

```
     ----- 8 -----
     |           |
  ---7---     ---6---
  |     |     |     |
 -7-   -4-   -5-   x5
 | |   | |   | |   x
 3 6   4 1   2 3   9
```

The 9 is not actually part of the heap anymore, but it is still part of the vector until you erase it, via a call `pop_back` or similar.

<sub>1. if the children are equal, as in the case of the adjacent 7's in the tree in your example, it could go either way. I believe that `std::pop_heap` sends it to the right, though I'm not sure if this is implementation defined</sub>

Comment: "The root node is swapped with the greater of its two children (if the children are equal, std::pop_heap sends it to the right), and this is repeated until it is at the bottom of the tree. Then it is swapped with the last element. " but how could you guarantee that's still a heap? for example if the "4" in the 9-8-7-4 changed to 3, after swapping the leaf node "4" originally at the right bottom will be bigger than the "3"!

Comment: @athos: You are correct. I missed a step at the end. The last swapped leaf is then pushed *up* the tree, if necessary, by swapping with its parent if the child is greater than the parent, which is repeated until the child is *not* greater than the parent.

Comment: @athos: Scratch all that, I'm an idiot. That's not what `std::pop_heap` does, though it would work, and have the same effect. It's actually much simpler. The root is swapped with the last element, which is then pushed down the tree. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first element in the vector is the root at index 0. Its left child is at index 1 and its right child at index 2. In general: `left_child(i) = 2 * i + 1` and `right_child(i) = 2 * i + 2` and `parent(i) = floor((i - 1) / 2)`

Another way to think about it is the heap fills each level from *left to right* in the tree. Following the elements in the vector the first level is 9 (1 value), second level 8 6 (2 values) and third level 7 7 5 5 (4 values), and so on. Both these ways will help you draw the heap in a tree structure when given a vector.